# Is it possible to determine which of these numbers is greater: $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{3}}$ or $\sqrt{3}^{\sqrt{2}}$ without approximating anything?

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

Is it possible to determine which of these numbers is greater: $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{3}}$ or $\sqrt{3}^{\sqrt{2}}$?

I tried to express both in terms of powers of 3, but in the first number I got $log_32 $ as part of the product of the overall power of two, which - again - makes things hard. 
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use the idea of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPHD7zmLVa8

Comment: To compare $x^y$ and $y^x$, it suffices to compare $(x^y)^{1/(xy)}=x^{1/x}$ and $(y^x)^{1/(xy)}=y^{1/y}$. To compare $x^{1/x}$ and $y^{1/y}$, it suffices to compare $(\log x)/x$ and $(\log y)/y$. The function $u(t)=(\log t)/t$ has derivative $u'(t)=-\log(t/e)/t^2$ hence it is increasing on $t$ in $(0,e)$. Now, $x=\sqrt2$ and $y=\sqrt3$ are such that $x<y<2<e$ hence $u(x)<u(y)$, hence $x^y<y^x$.

Answer (score 6):

We compare
$$\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{3} \text{ vs. } \sqrt{3}^\sqrt{2}$$
or (taking natural logarithms)
$$(\sqrt{3}/2) \ln 2 \text{ vs. } (\sqrt{2}/2) \ln 3$$ or (multiplying by $2$) $$\sqrt{3} \ln 2 \text{ vs. } \sqrt{2} \ln 3$$ or (rearranging) $$\sqrt{3/2} \text{ vs. } (\ln3)/(\ln2) = \log_2 3.$$

Now $2^{\sqrt{3/2}} < 2^{3/2} = 2 \sqrt{2} < 3$, because $(2\sqrt{2})^2 = 8$ whereas $3^2 = 9$. Thus $\sqrt{3/2} < \log_2 3$ and we conclude $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{3}} < \sqrt{3}^{\sqrt{2}}$, chasing back the comparisons.

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=(\ln x)/x$. Calculus tells  us this increases for $x<e$ and
decreases for $x>e$. Therefore $f(\sqrt2)<f(\sqrt3)$ and so
$\sqrt3\ln\sqrt2<\sqrt2\ln\sqrt3$. Exponentiating: $\sqrt2^{\sqrt3}<\sqrt3^{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(\sqrt3^\sqrt2)^\sqrt3>(\sqrt3^\sqrt2)^\sqrt2=\sqrt9>\sqrt8=(\sqrt2^\sqrt3)^\sqrt3$$ now using $a^x>b^x$ implies $a>b$ we conclude that $\sqrt3^\sqrt2$ is bigger.

Comment: This solution is excellent, but a quick comment that $a^x > b^x \Rightarrow a > b$ is only true when the variables are all positive (plus some other edge cases).